# Schemas to deserialize JSON string in python

Tags: python, json

I would like to deserialize JSON of which I predefined the schema.
Here is a typical JSON file I deal with.

```
{'op': 'mcm',
 'id': 1,
 'clk': 'AKjT4QEAl5q/AQCW7rIB',
 'pt': 1563999965598,
 'mc': [{'id': '1.160679253',
   'rc': [{'atl': [[1.18, 88.5],
      [1.17, 152.86],
      [1.16, 175.96],
      [1.14, 93.3],
      [1.08, 28.08],
      [1.07, 8.84],
      [1.02, 129.74]],
     'id': 1}]}]}
```

for which I would like a schema like that:

```
{'op': String,
 'id': Integer,
 'clk': String,
 'pt': Integer,
 'mc': [{'id': String,
   'rc': [{'atl': Array(Decimal),
     'id': Integer}]}]}
```

I know it is possible to do that with PySpark but I am looking for a lighter solution (something on the top of the `json` packages for example).

Here is what I already tried so far:

- **deserializing the JSON file and having a custom function to set up the type of each of the elements of the dictionary**: I am afraid that by converting from string to float and then from float to Decimal I would get rounding errors.
- **Use a custom `JSONDecoder` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONDecoder) with custom `parse_float`, `parse_int`, `parse_constant` function**: those functions only take the string to be parsed as an argument and I would have to treat `'1.160679253'` (just after `pt`) and  `'1.18'`  (just after `atl`) the same way while I want `'1.160679253'` to remain a string and `'1.18'` to be cast as decimal.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Could you give an example of such a custom function from your first point? I'm wondering why do you feel the need to convert from String->Float->Decimal instead of just using the `Decimal()` function right away

Comment: I thought that when we call the load function in JSON, it will automatically convert elements that look like float to float and I would have to convert them to Decimal which would give this sequence of conversions: String -> Float -> Decimal.

Comment: Yes, I figured that after a moment of thinking, that's why I suggested forcing JSON parser to convert float-looking fields to Decimals straight away to avoid information loss. I thought you may not be aware that it's an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first approach is the most lightweight one as it requires nothing but the standard library - just use a custom function based on `json` package tailored to what you need. As for the float->decimal conversion and precision loss, `json.loads()` has `parse_float` parameter to force floating number parsing as Decimals straight away:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> json.loads('1.1', parse_float=decimal.Decimal)
Decimal('1.1')
```

As for the ID field, which will be parsed to `Decimal` as well thanks to its unique float-similar format - you can just convert it back to string via `str()` with no information loss as a special case.

Comment: Thanks, what you suggest is the second thing I tried and it would convert `'1.160679253'` in `'id': '1.160679253'` to Decimal as well while I want to keep it as a String

Comment: Well, then just convert this single field back to string in the custom function - no information will be lost in this conversion and this field is clearly a special case, as usually strings meant to be strings don't look like decimals.

Comment: Isn't it possible that when I convert it back I will get rounding errors ?

Comment: In the end I am going to force `json.loads()` to keep everything as String and add a custom function that will convert all the strings in the dictionary one by one. That way I can cast the each element depending on its key.

Comment: What rounding errors? Decimal->String as performed by `str(decimal)` doesn't do any rounding at all. `>>> d = decimal.Decimal('0.1428571428571428571428571429')
>>> str(d)
'0.1428571428571428571428571429'`

Comment: Faire enough, I did not know it, thank you. Can you add that to your answer and I will validate it.